# Binary neighbours of decimal number

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have decimal numbers between `0` and `2^L`. Each of those decimal numbers can be represented as a binary number of length `L`. I am now interested in a function which takes a single decimal number and then computes all `L` decimal numbers for which the binary representation only differs in one position. I am interested in the most fast solution for this problem.
Example:

`L=3--> Numbers between 0 and 7
F(2) = (0,3,6)
since 
2= 010 -> 0=000, 3=011, 6=110`

Hope you have an idea and thanks in advance :)

Comment: A simple loop that flips one bit at a time isn’t fast enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bit-shifts to do this:

```
def neighbors(n, bitLength):
    return map(lambda b: n ^ (1 << b), range(bitLength))

>>> print(list(neighbors(2, 3)))
[3, 0, 6]
```

They're about the fastest mathematical operation that can be done with a classical computer and for powers of two, they're perfect.

Comment: @HighwayJohn You're welcome. Python's built-in functions are written in C, as are the mathematical operators. Therefore they run faster than code you write yourself in Python. Furthermore, bit-shift operations run very quickly because the actual gate structure is much simpler than for mathematical operations.

Answer (score 3):

A pure python implementation using the xor operator `^`

```
def neighbors(n, bits):
    for bit in range(bits):
        yield n ^ (2 ** bit)
```

It works with your example numbers.

```
>>> list(neighbors(2, 3))
[3, 0, 6]
```

Here's a numpy solution that creates an outer product from an sequence of numbers.

```
import numpy as np

def array_neighbors(numbers, bits=8):
    flip_bits = 2 ** np.arange(bits)
    return np.bitwise_xor.outer(numbers, flip_bits)
```

The output is a 2d array with one row for each input number and where the columns correspond to the flipped bit positions.

```
>>> array_neighbors([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3)
[[1 2 4]
 [0 3 5]
 [3 0 6]
 [2 1 7]
 [5 6 0]
 [4 7 1]
 [7 4 2]
 [6 5 3]]
```

This is quite fast, and can process a large array of integers in a few milliseconds.

```
>>> a_million_numbers = np.random.randint(0, 256, 1_000_000)
>>> %timeit array_neighbors(a_million_numbers)
67.8 ms ± 3.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!